# How to avoid Fast Recovery (SDS) in Informix server?

Tags: informix

I have two Informix servers which are connected with an SDS (shared-disk secondary) connection. Suddenly, the secondary node has been downed and once I start it, it goes to fast recovery mode. But it is not changing it's state to online. Instead of that, the secondary node is remaining in fast recovery mode for a very long time. Is there any way to skip the fast recovery mode or get the secondary node  back to online as soon as possible.

```
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.xxxx -- Fast Recovery (SDS)
```

Comment: Observation: it would be a good idea to move from 11.70 to a more recent version — 12.10 or 14.10 are your options.  There isn't enough information in the question to resolve your problem(s).  It would be sensible to show what's in the `xxxx` information; it is only a version number.  The platform might be relevant.  The key information missing is the information in the secondary online log file just before the secondary went down, which might provide information about why it went down.  Also of relevance is the online log file since you started it and it got stuck in fast recovery.

Comment: Presumably you're running on at least two machines.  Can you connect to the primary server from the secondary?  If not, that may be the problem for the secondary too.  Do you have technical support?  If so, you should contact your technical support provider.  This is a 'down system' situation; those are normally treated with priority.